# Mosquitto failing to authenticate

Tags: raspberry-pi, mosquitto

I genuinely have no idea what I'm doing wrong. But no matter how many different ways I try to set a username and password for my mosquitto server, the connection is not authorized.
This seems like such a simple process I'm not even sure what to ask. But here's the tutorial I followed: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-username-password-example/

I tried both methods, and I know for a fact I'm typing my username and password in right: `mosquitto_sub -d -t MessageBoard -u ServerPi -p *******`, but all I receive in return is:

> Error: Connection refused

Here is my config:

```
listener 1883
persistence true
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
```

Edit: The actual command I used a capital -P. For some reason when using the correct username and password it’s still not authorizing me.

Comment: Edit the question to include the broker logs (in verbose mode when it fails to authenticate)

Answer (score 0):

The password option is `-P`, not `-p`. `-p` means port.

"Error: Connection refused" means that TCP indicated nothing was listening on the port, which can be caused by the broker not running, the broker not listening on that port, or sometimes a firewall. You'd see an "unauthorized" error if you gave the wrong password, but you're not getting that far because you're using the wrong option, causing `mosquitto_sub` to try to connect to the wrong port.

Unless your password is all numbers I'm surprised and disappointed that `mosquitto_sub` isn't warning you that the port number is invalid.

For more information on `mosquitto_sub`, please see its [man page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html).

Comment: hmm, passing a string for the port number gives me a `Error: No such file or directory` which I understand (only because I know how it works), but should be better message

Comment: The broker is running I have a dedicated raspberry pi running only the server. Everything works perfectly fine if I have allow anonymous to true. I’ve been using the server for two weeks.  But the moment I set anonymous to false even with the correct -P it won’t let me connect. I either get the error mentioned above or Connak(5) unauthorized.

Comment: To further clarify when I made that post I copied my most recently ran cli command and that was just me attempting a lowercase p incase I was just doing something simple wrong. But for the last week I have been trying the -P. Every time I get an unauthorized error even though my username and password is right.

Comment: @hardlib thanks, I was away from my computer and couldn't try it out myself when I replied last night. That's still better than just accepting it and turning it into 0 would be.

Comment: @Chase B. for future questions it helps if you post the actual command and error you're getting; otherwise you're just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @romkey my apologies I didn’t notice the capitalization difference. The issue still persists though.